# Not all embedded Youtube videos play on iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I've been using the standard method to embed a Youtube video in a UIWebview as a thumbnail to give the appearance of playing the video in the iPhone app.

But many times the video either gives a broken play button or returns after 1 minute or so that the video could not be played.

I assume this is because the poster either didn't make the video public yet, or maybe it hadn't been converted to iPhone format yet?  Anyway, is there any way to check for this in the API JSON or Atom feed?  I looked thru every tag and couldn't find anything that would clearly confirm the video is not playable on the iPhone.

Comment: Quite simply, not all YouTube videos have an MP4 copy. I ran into this same issue. As time goes on, more and more videos will have an iPhone-compatible counterpart but right now it's not 100%. You could use stringWithFormat to dynamically come up with the MP4 address, and test it first before trying to present it. if the download fails in the background, you know an MP4 is not available.

Comment: Thanks Cirrostratus.  That's what I was afraid of. I thought I read somewhere that Youtube was converting ALL new videos to h.264/m4v, but that is obviously not the case.  Most of the time the embedding works fine, but c'est la vie.  I thought Youtube didn't expose the mp4 address anymore though?

Comment: Never mind. Found a way.

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone does not natively support flash, so I don't see why it could support rendering the youtube player within a UIWebView. Perhaps you should try using an .mp4.